# Neo4j 2.1.7 for Social Network Analysis using Java API of Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, social-networking

I am using Neo4j 2.1.7 community edition in Windows and I have successfully created 100 nodes with 1000 relationships between them (randomly assigned). what i need is how can i use the BetweennessCentrality, ClosenessCentrality etc. classes of org.neo4j.graphalgo package in order to calcualte centrality measures  of my sample database?

I have checked some resources at

1- http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo/2.1.6/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/centrality/BetweennessCentrality.java?av=f

2- http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.neo4j.graphalgo.impl.util.DoubleAdder (I tried to copy the codes here, but it said no such a constructor for `SingleSourceShortestPathDijkstra<Double>` )

3- http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.neo4j.graphalgo.impl.centrality.ClosenessCentrality  (this says there is no example)

So, can anyone please provide me some code snippets for calculating centrality measures and if possible some guideline to calculate community detection algorithms in Neo4j?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you can share the code you wrote so far, e.g. in a GitHub project?

Comment: Please be aware that the classes you've mentioned are not part of Neo4j's public API.